# "Давач", "датчик", "сенсор"?

Tags: переклад, терміни, синоніми

СУМ 11 знає лише "[датчик](http://sum.in.ua/s/datchyk)". СУМ 20 вже вказує і [давач](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=162581&page=703). [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%87) наводить всі три варіанти.

Який варіант краще? Чи можна вважати ці слова повними синонімами?

Comment: Щоб відповісти на запитання «який варіант краще», треба знати контекст. Усі слова саме тому і існують, що по-різному використовуються у різних контекстах.

Answer (score 6):

ДНТБ України, [термінологічний центр](https://dntb.gov.ua/about-dntbu/%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80) рекомендує **датник**:

> У сучасній українській мові немає усталеного вживання якогось певного
>   варіанта на позначення цього поняття.
>
> Варіант “*датчик” є калькою з російської мови і суперечить нормам
>   українського словотворення, де суфікс «-чик» є рідковживаним. Отже,
>   він невдалий за ознакою органічності.
>
> Варіант “*давач” виник шляхом необґрунтованого застосування того
>   самого суфіксального механізму, за яким утворено й термін “передавач”
>   (рос. “передатчик“). Статистичний метод показує, що суфікс
>   “-ач” / “-яч” є частовживаним термінотвірним елементом: *передавач,
>   приймач, подавач, змішувач, повторювач, тягач, виділяч* тощо. А з
>   порівняльного та компонентного аналізу (елементи аналітичного методу)
>   бачимо, що цей суфікс притаманний активному виконавцю (актанту) дії,
>   позначуваної основою: *передавач* передає, *приймач* приймає, *змішувач*
>   змішує тощо. Разом з тим, терміни “датчик давления“, “датчик тока“,
>   “датчик перенапряжений“ і под. позначають пристрій, який лише фіксує
>   величину тиску, струму чи наявність перенапруг, але зовсім не
>   зумовлює, не задає, не генерує їх. Своєю чергою, поширений суфікс
>   “-ник” позначає співвіднесеність із поняттям, вираженим основою, і є
>   нейтральним щодо актантності – *золотник, качатник, квітник, кутник,
>   літник, маятник, поворотник, прикметник, супутник, цитатник* тощо.
>
> Відповідно до ознак вдалого терміна, варіант *давач* є неточним
>   (оскільки семантично відповідає активному виконавцю дії), породжує
>   хибні асоціації щодо актантності, а також порушує вимогу системності.
>   Він також недостатньо гнучкий щодо творення похідних прикметників
>   (**давачевий*). З іншого боку, варіант датник не має таких недоліків і
>   трохи поступається лише за ознакою стислості (шість літер проти
>   п’яти). Таким чином, варіант *давач* порушує чотири вимоги до вдалого
>   терміна (серед яких є найважливіші – точність і суттєвість).
>
> Отже, рекомендуємо вживати форму *датник*.
>
> Цю форму подає «Тлумачний словник із фізики», який має гриф
>   Міністерства освіти і науки України і, відповідно до Розпорядження
>   Президії НАН України № 161 від 12.03.2013, міститься в переліку
>   нормативних словників української мови.
>
> Літ.: Вакуленко М. О. Українська термінологія: комплексний
>   лінгвістичний аналіз : [монографія]. Івано-Франківськ : Фоліант. 2015.
>   361 с., іл.; Вакуленко М. О., Вакуленко О. В. Тлумачний словник із
>   фізики : [6644 статті]. К. : Видавничо-поліграфічний центр “Київський
>   університет”, 2008. 767 с.; Vakulenko, Maksym. 2018. From
>   Terminology-Vocabulary to Terminology-Science: A Ukrainian Trend. Beau
>   Bassin : LAP. 120 p.

Comment: Основна мета не дати, а відчути. Хибний напрямок набирає голоси. Дивно це все.

Answer (score 1):

Визначення взяті з Великого тлумачного словника сучасної української мови

> ***[Датчик](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53396/857458.html)*** -а, ч. Вхідна чутлива частина автоматичного або
>   телемеханічного пристрою, яка сприймає зовнішні подразнення і передає
>   їх відповідно переробленими на інші частини пристрою (фотоелементи,
>   термопари, електромагнітні та п'єзоелектричні звукознімачі тощо).
>
> ***[Сенсор](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53409/982899.html)*** -а, ч. 1》 спец. Датчик; елемент, що сприймає дотик, зміну
>   температури, освітлення, швидкості та ін. з подальшою передачею на
>   вимірювальні або керуючі прилади. 2》 Людина, що володіє чутливістю
>   шкіри. 3》 фізіол. Окремий рецептор або рецепторний орган (око, вухо та
>   ін.).
>
> ***[Давач](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53396/857092.html)*** -а, ч. Той, хто дає що-небудь.

Всі три слова мають різне значення, тому використовувати їх як повні синоніми не можна. Хоча слова ***"сенсор"*** і ***"датчик"*** мають одне більш схоже визначення, але слід їх використовувати не як взаємозамінні, а залежно від контексту.

На питання: *"Який варіант краще?"* потрібно розуміти в якому контексті слово використовується.

Comment: а чому ви в цьому питання скористувалися лише одним словником?

Answer (score 1):

Як бачите на самій [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA), на яку ви опираєтеся в своєму запитанні, є розділ "Давач чи датчик", де вказано, що слово "датчик" увійшло в українську мову як калька з російської, тому хоч він і зафіксований у деяких сучасних словниках, вживати не бажано.

Що до слова "сенсора", то це також запозичення з англійської (слово "sensor"), тому навіщо вживати запозичені слова, коли є українське "давач"?

Окрім цього, якщо ви заглянете на сайт [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/sensor), то побачити, що відповідником до слова сенсор є не лише "давач", але й "чутливець", однак такого слово немає в СУМі, тому все таки краще "давач".

До речі, на тому ж [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/datchyk) люди шукали відповідник до слова "датчик", і саме "давач" там на першому місці.

Comment: Як на мене, то *давач руху* це те, що дає рух. Так само *давач енергії*, *давач струму*, *давач яблук* тощо.

Answer (score 0):

Сьогодні останній день місяця, то ж надсилав показання лічильників по комунальним послугам. Зачепило слово *покази*. Знайшов цей допис на сайті. Перечитав відповіді. Жахнувся неоковирним варіантам *датник* і *давач*. Здивувався, що за 4 роки у відповідях до цього допису не було згадано очевидного варіанту. /rant mode off

### покажчик (показник)

> пока́жчик
> 2. Контрольно-вимірювальний прилад.
> *Покажчик температури води призначений для контролю за температурою води у системі охолодження двигуна* (Підручник шофера, 1960, 167). — [Академічний тлумачний словник української мови (СУМ)](http://sum.in.ua/s/pokazhchyk)

Особисто мені цей варіант подобається тим, що слово базується на питомому корені *«показ-»*. Окрім того, корінь «дат-», як і його латинський прообраз, «dat-», мені здаються перевантаженими різноманітними сенсами (в тому числі, наприклад, значенням «день і місяць року».

Критика цього варіанту може ґрунтуватися на різниці між «пристроєм для вимірювання фізичної величини» і «пристроєм для відображення результатів», що не завжди одне і те саме (термометр охолоджувальної рідини двигуна автівки знаходиться під капотом у той час, як значення показується на панелі приладів у салоні).

Інший словник пропонує ще гарний варіант, хоча чомусь позначає, що це розмовне слово:

> […] розмовне *показник*; (теплоти) вимірювач; […]
> — [Словник синонімів Караванського](http://slovopedia.org.ua/41/53407/271026.html)

Знов-таки, не без критики. Слово *показник* також має значення «одне конкретне значення вимірюваної величини». А не лише пристрій, який цю величину вимірює.

У будь-якому випадку, особисто мені ці варіанти подобаються більше, ніж ті, що запропоновані у сусідніх відповідях.

Comment: Власне, через вказану вами проблему (може не показувати) це слово не підходить. От на Словотворі *чутник* пропонують.

Comment: @Yola, *чутник* мені більше подобається. Як *сенсор*, тільки більш питомий. Не бажаєте написати у вигляді відповіді?

Comment: Інколи слово треба просто побудувати самому ...